# monitor EKS Cluster using AppDynamics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod, appdynamics, performance-monitor

I have an Elastic Kubernetes Cluster(EKS) running in AWS , In the cluster many services and pods are running  .I want to use AppDynamics to monitor the services and pods . I am new to AppDynamics so I don't know much about it . but i am confused in some areas

1. What are the performance metrics(CPU usages , no of instances... ) should I use for monitor the
   cluster
2. How can I monitor the cluster , how to setup AWS with AppDynamics to monitor everything

Answer (score 0):

The Cluster Agent is used for monitoring AWS EKS, additionally the Cluster Agent Operator can be used to setup additional Infra / Network monitoring.

Compatibility: https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/infrastructure-visibility/monitor-kubernetes-with-the-cluster-agent/cluster-agent-requirements-and-supported-environments

Install (Cluster Agent): https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/infrastructure-visibility/monitor-kubernetes-with-the-cluster-agent/install-the-cluster-agent

(You will need to grab / build an image and then install using Kubernetes CLI or the Cluster Agent Helm Chart)

Install (Infra Agent / Network Visibility - requires the Cluster Agent): https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/infrastructure-visibility/monitor-kubernetes-with-the-cluster-agent/install-the-cluster-agent/install-infrastructure-visibility-with-the-cluster-agent-operator

Metrics: https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/infrastructure-visibility/monitor-kubernetes-with-the-cluster-agent/use-the-cluster-agent/monitor-cluster-health

As to what Metrics to actively monitor this is a bit subjective, however there are plenty of guides around to help, e.g:

- https://www.kubermatic.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-kubernetes-metrics/
- https://sematext.com/blog/kubernetes-metrics/